# How to attach an image to an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been trying to figure this out for a while.
I can't figure out how to make a bot attach an image to an embed.
I'm trying to upload a picture from my PC.

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const discord = require('discord.js')

class HoundCommand extends commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'hound',
      group: 'simple',
      memberName: 'hound',
      description: 'Tells info about hound'
    });
  }

  async run(message, args) {
    var myInfo = new discord.RichEmbed()
      .setTitle("Hound")
      .addField("Name", "Hound")
      .addField("Age", "12")
      .addField("Description", "Im good at siege, I stream occasionally and ya")
      .setColor("#020B0C")
    message.channel.sendEmbed(myInfo);
  }
}

module.exports = HoundCommand;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please? Attach an image where? Under the embed? In the embed? Which field and place?

Comment: in the embed, under description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want your image uploaded from your local disk you need to tell the Discord embed exactly that.
Every embed has a [.attachFile()](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=attachFile) method, where you can upload a file from local disk and directly use this in your embed with the following syntax: `attachment://fileName.extension`

So as an example with an file called avatar.png you would need

```js
var myInfo = new discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("Hound")
  .addField("Name", "Hound")
  .addField("Age", "12")
  .addField("Description", "Im good at siege, I stream occasionally and ya")
  .setColor("#020B0C")
  .attachFile('./avatar.png')
  .setImage('attachment://avatar.png');
message.channel.sendEmbed(myInfo);
```

If you need to upload multiple files at once, use the [.attachFiles()](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=attachFiles) method.

Answer (score 0):

This has been depreciated with v14
In `discord.js` v14, we have a new way of sending attachments. We now have [`AttachmentBuilder`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/AttachmentBuilder) but the code change should be pretty easy. Just import [`AttachmentBuilder`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/AttachmentBuilder) from discord.js