# There is a way to get the canvas buffer to a Discord embed attachment?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I basically wanted to make a welcome embed for who joins the server with a nicely formatted embed. I processed my image on canvas and put it in a buffer thanks to the function `const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');`, but when I tried to put the attachment to the embed attachment image, that failed. Can someone tell me how to get the custom processed image to the embed image?

**Error**

```
Unhandled promise rejection: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.image.url: Could not interpret "{'name': 'welcome-image.png'}" as string.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/user/Sviluppo/Discord/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/665623291951841380/messages',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400
}
```

**All canvas code I made**

```
// Sends a welcome when a new member join (memo: command to set the IDWelcomeChannel var)
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === '665623291951841380');
    if (!channel) return;

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper-welcome.jpg');
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Slightly smaller text placed above the member's display name
    ctx.font = '28px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText('Welcome to the server,', canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 3.5);

    // Add an exclamation point here and below
    const applyText = (canvas, text) => {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        let fontSize = 70;
        do {
            // Assign the font to the context and decrement it so it can be measured again
            ctx.font = `${fontSize -= 10}px sans-serif`;
            // Compare pixel width of the text to the canvas minus the approximate avatar size
        } while (ctx.measureText(text).width > canvas.width - 300);
    
        // Return the result to use in the actual canvas
        return ctx.font;
    };
    ctx.font = applyText(canvas, `${member.displayName}!`);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.fillText(`${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.8);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clip();

    const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' }));
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

    const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');

    let wembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor('Welcome there!')
        .setDescription(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!, be sure to check out <#661731407789424651> and the rules at <#662584102679085066>. Thanks for being with us! Hope you will have a good time here!`)
        .attachFiles(attachment)
        .setImage(attachment)
    channel.send(wembed);

    //channel.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}!, be sure to check out`, infoCh, `and the rules at`, rulesCh, `. Thanks for being with us! Hope you will have a good time here!`, attachment);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use a local image on a discord.js rich embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199950/how-do-i-use-a-local-image-on-a-discord-js-rich-embed), [How to attach an image to an embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067769/how-to-attach-an-image-to-an-embed)

Comment: Yeah thanks that helps! But unfortunately the canvas loads on a buffer function, so he doesn't actually store the **modified** image locally, but the blank one

Comment: That has nothing to do with the actual strategy you use to attach the `MessageAttachment` to your embed. You already figured out how to use the canvas buffer to make an attachment, you can find how to attach it to an embed correctly in either question I linked.

Comment: Sure thing! Thanks